# How to display special characters on heatmap

Tags: r, plot, special-characters

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
                        V2   V3 V4   V5   V6    V7
PPAR Signaling        1.32 1.41  0 1.61 1.36 1.210
PPARα/RXRα Activation 0.00 0.00  0 1.34 1.10 0.944
```

With this code:

```
    dat <- structure(list(V2 = c(1.32, 0), V3 = c(1.41, 0), V4 = c(0L, 0L
    ), V5 = c(1.61, 1.34), V6 = c(1.36, 1.1), V7 = c(1.21, 0.944)), .Names = c("V2", 
    "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), row.names = c("PPAR Signaling", 
    "PPARα/RXRα Activation"), class = "data.frame")


   ## Actual data can be found here http://dpaste.com/2AYAPSX/

   ## In reality the data is read using 
   # dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/2AYAPSX/",sep="\t")
   # dat(rownames) <- dat$V1
   # dat$V1 <- NULL

    heatmap(as.matrix(dat))
```

It produces heat map like this:
[image]

Note that the Greek letter is changed to `..`. 
How can I display Greek letter the properly?

**Update: Session info**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Can you post your `sesssionInfo()`? This is an encoding issue; resolving coding issues varies strongly by platform.

Comment: @nograpes: I updated the session info.

Comment: If you wish to avoid hardcoded solution, it might be easier to do something with your OS setting. As a matter of fact, using your code, my machine displayed Greek letters in heatmap() output 'out of box' (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on your platform. I tried RStudio, and plain R, and both times it worked using your code. Can you try upgrading R to 3.1.0? It is the only difference.

Comment: Also, are you having this problem when displaying the heatmap on the screen, or is it only a problem when you write to a file?

Comment: works for me too. writing to a file, in r, and rstudio. just upgrade

Comment: @rawr, are you seeing it as `a` or as `α`?

Comment: very clearly alpha, from the OP's original code. v3.1.0 @DavidArenburg

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, I too clearly see `α` from the original code. Only writing to a pdf breaks it. (Or using Windows).

Comment: @nograpes, so my guess me and the OP both using windows as we both get that error

Comment: @DavidArenburg No, he is using Mac OS, take a look at the Session Info.

Comment: @nograpes: both on screen and write into files.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
heatmap(as.matrix(dat), labRow =c("PPAR Signaling",
                                   expression(paste("PPAR",alpha,"/RXR", alpha, " Activation"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer not hardcoded because in reality there are hundreds of rows with Greeks.

Comment: you might want to include a more representative sample of your data, then.